# Unknown return type for a virtual function in C++

Tags: c++, function, types, return, virtual

So, I have a base class which is abstract because of my function:

```
virtual void my_value() = 0;
```

Then in two different classes which inherit my base class I need to pre-define this function so that in the first it returns an integer and in the other a float. Can that be done?

P.S. I know void variant isn't gonna work, I would also like to point out that conversion from float to integer is not good enough.

Comment: No, overrides for virtual functions must return the same type, or a "covariant" type (which roughly means a derived type). `int` and `double` are not covariant with `void`

Comment: You can't. You might use a type like [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html), but in general this indicates a flaw in your program design.

Comment: If that's all the variation you need, you can use a `union` consisting of an `int` and a `float`. If the return type is going keep on expanding, then Boost Any would be a better choice.